# How to instantiate an empty JTable?

Tags: swing, jtable

I am climbing the java learning curve, and for the first time I need a JTable.  What I would like to do is display an empty table, with all cells vacant except for column headings.  Then as a result of user actions, the tables is filled with a mix of strings, integers, and floats.

All the examples I find on the web create tables that are populated at instantiation.  Is there any simple way to defer populating the table, but displaying it at startup?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a table model with the specified number of rows and columns and use that for your JTable. For example:

```
String[] colHeadings = {"COLUMN1","COLUMN2"};
int numRows = 5 ;
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(numRows, colHeadings.length) ;
model.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeadings);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

You can then call methods on the model to update values, add rows etc.

Comment: This compiled, and showed the table, but not the column titles.  It certainly is a straightforward way to get a table. I'm putting up a separate question with the code.

Comment: To display the columns, the easiest way is to put your table into a scroll pane:
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

This is what I did for an old project. I set all of the cells to null and since I only wanted a table with 4 rows and 4 columns, it was easy to initialize all of them in the declaration statement.

```
jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
   new Object [][] {
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                   }, new String [] {"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"}
                ));
```

Then to update the rows and/or columns use the following method ...

```
jTable1.setValueAt(Object data, int row, int column);
```

or for multiple rows or columns, use a loop. Good luck.